# Crystal Reports 13 And Asp.Net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I'm developing a website using Asp.Net 3.5 in Visual Studio 2008 and we use Crystal Reports 10 (that's come together vs2008).

Last Year, We migrate it to Visual Studio 2010 but we still use .Net 3.5 in our website. Vs2010 does not come with Crystal Reports, so we download Crystal 13 (for vs2010) from SAP business object and install in my develop machine (Sdk kit and runtime).

It works fine, we changed the references in web.config from Crystal 10 to Crystal 13 and it's working in our develop machine.

We still using Asp.Net 3.5.

Now the problem... I host my website in our server (I also install the runtime) and I get this exception with a message:

*"Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."*

In web.config the exception:

Can anybody help me ?
Is possible use .Net 3.5 with Crystal 13 ? Or other solution (version) for Crystal?

**Edits**

```
<compilation debug="false" strict="false" explicit="true">
    <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
    </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
      <add extension=".rpt" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.Compilation.RptBuildProvider, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
  </buildProviders>
</compilation>
```

Comment: do you  ***system.web section*** `<httpHandlers>
      <add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web`

and ***system.webServer section*** `<handlers>
      <add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web` ?

Comment: It's a question from 2012. I really can't remember!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I believe you are not the only one who has problems when trying to deploy Crystal Report for VS 2010. Based on the error message you had, have you checked:

1. Please make sure you just have one CR version installed on your system. If you do have other CR version installed, consider to uninstall it so that your application is not "confused" about the CR version.
2. You need to make sure you download the correct CR version. Since you are using VS 2010, you need to refer to [CRforVS_redist_install_64bit_13_0_1.zip](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_64bit_13_0_1.zip) (for 64 bit machine) or [CRforVS_redist_install_32bit_13_0_1.zip](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_32bit_13_0_1.zip) (for 32 bit machine). These two are the redistributable packages. You can download full package from the below link as well: [CRforVS_13_0_1.exe](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_1.exe)  **Note: It is sometimes necessary to install 32bit CR runtime even on 64bit OS**
3. Make sure you setup FULL TRUST permission on your root folder
4. The LOCAL SERVICE permission must be setup on your application pool
5. Make sure the aspnet_client folder exists on your root folder.

If you can make sure all the 5 points above, your Crystal Report should work without any fuss.

Another important thing to note down here is that if you host your Crystal Report with a shared host, you need to check it with them of whether they really support Crystal Report. If you still have problems, you can switch to http://www.asphostcentral.com, who provides Crystal Report support.

Good luck!

Comment: I've installed the 32bits version in my O.S. I don't know why it's happening but now it's running fine! Thanks

Comment: how does one setup FULL TRUST permission on the root folder?  Hos does one setup the LOCAL SERVICE permission on your application pool?  What is considered the "root folder" in this scenario?

Comment: how can i check "FULL TRUST permission of root folder" and "LOCAL SERVICE permission must be setup on application pool" ?

Comment: ***compilation section*** is _required_ and maybe ***system.web section*** `<httpHandlers>
      <add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web`

and ***system.webServer section*** `<handlers>
      <add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web`

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem and resolved it by making sure all references to the previous version of crystal from the Web Config file, the server, and the publishing  workstation were removed. Other than the full trust basically everything that user707217 did,  I did and it worked for my upgraded Web application

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem. I solved install [this setup](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_64bit_13_0_1.zip). (I use vs 2015 (4.6))

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue because of some dll files were missing from References of VS13. I went to the location http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824 and installed the newest pack. It resolved the issue.