# Configuration Error in web.config for crystall report

Tags: crystal-reports, web-config

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:

Line 29:         
Line 30:         
Line 31:         
Line 32:         
Line 33:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the crystal report redistribution package.

you can see this article [Crystal Reports 13 And Asp.Net 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193887/crystal-reports-13-and-asp-net-3-5?rq=1)

And can get the files you need at this address [SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio: Updates & Runtime Downloads](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824)