# Crystal report logon fail on client computer after correct Installation

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

The developer computer have 2 VS(2008,2013) and many crystal report installed.(see image)
I created 2 app(A,B) from VS2008(A) and vs2013(B) with CR.
I install both of A,B to client computer by Clickonce.
It work fine on developer Com but for client computer. CR in App B(VS2013) work fine but **CR in App A(VS2008) cannot connect data base**. it show window ask for database/password and then, Show "Logon failed".(see image)
Please advice.

Coding for show report (use for both A,B App)

```
    Dim crtableLogoninfo As New TableLogOnInfo()
    Dim crConnectionInfo As New ConnectionInfo()
    Dim CrTables As Tables
    Dim CrTable As Table
    Dim rptDoc As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument = New crpPlanApv  
    With crConnectionInfo
        .ServerName = "bom"         
        .DatabaseName = "ProductDataBase"
        .UserID = "khomsan"
        .Password = "123456"
    End With
    CrTables = rptDoc.Database.Tables
    For Each CrTable In CrTables
        crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo
        crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo
        CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo)
    Next
    With CrystalReportViewer1
        .ReportSource = rptDoc
        .Refresh()
        .Zoom(2)
    End With
```

[Crystal Report installed on Developer Computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwSZ5.jpg)

[When CR Logon Failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzecY.jpg)

Comment: tell me about the version of Crystal in the project references as well as the app.config (or web.config) files on both applications

Comment: vs2008 use CR10.5.3700.0, vs2013 use CR13.0.3500.0

Comment: before we troubleshoot the crystal version, have you tried `rptDoc.SetDatabaseLogon("credentials")`? I made the jump from Crystal 10.5 to 13.5, and it's a one way jump. You can use the 13.5 references in VS2008, but let's exhaust other options first.

Comment: I will try on monday. please wait.

Comment: @reckface That function need password too. Where is to insert?

Comment: before `CrTables = rptDoc.Database.Tables`

Comment: @reckface Not work. Do you have any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the SQL Server 2005 Native Client ODBC and install to the problem computer.
 This is [link](https://www.connectionstrings.com/download-sql-server-native-client/).
1. Click **Feature Pack for Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - February 2007** from the web page
2. Checkbox one of the installation packages (msi). Make sure you choose the right version:
sqlncli.msi for 32-bit
sqlncli_x64.msi for 64-bit
sqlncli_ia64.msi for Itanium

Answer (score 0):

Change your Visual Studio 2008 project to reference the Crystal 13.x binaries, the same as you have in your VS2013 project.

Take note of the section referencing those libraries in the newer project. You should have references like:

`CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Design, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL`

See [Crystal Reports 13 And Asp.Net 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193887/crystal-reports-13-and-asp-net-3-5) for an example, but note that it uses 13.0.2, so adjust yours accordingly.

**Edit**

Delete the references to the version 10, then reference the same version you have in VS2013 that works. Look into your vbproj file in xml editor to ensure that you don't have version 10 of the Crystal runtime.

Finally edit the report, and verify that the data source is the same SQL client as your 2013 version.

Comment: I have changed all concern ref. as v.13. but still unworkable. I am not sure understand you at the 2nd sentence onwards. you just meaning i should note to my code if i have new project.(My english is very bad)

Comment: i do as your edit but not check in xml because i don't know where. but the same fail. it still same asking and logon fails.

Comment: right click your project in visual studio, open file location, then edit your .vbproj file with a text editor. Check the references. Also, Have you edited the report to set datasource?

Comment: As i see in xml of both app, i found the difference about BootstrapperPackage Include.  App vs2013 use SAP.CrystalReports14.NET.2.0. App vs2008 use BusinessObjects.CrystalReports.10.5.

Comment: Fixed !  I have download the SQL Server 2005 Native Client ODBC and just install it. This is [link](https://www.connectionstrings.com/download-sql-server-native-client)